# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars in matrix multiply

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, runtime-error

i want to multiply matrixes with big values
     here is my code

```
import time
import numpy


def mm( mtx_a, mtx_b):
tpos_b = zip( *mtx_b)
rtn = [[ sum( ea*eb for ea,eb in zip(a,b)) for b in tpos_b] for a in mtx_a]
return rtn

print ("first part of project of OS")
N=input("select the size of N*N matrix by entering the power of 10 \n")

N=10**N
startTime = time.time()

try:
    P=numpy.random.randint(-100,100,size=(N,N))
    Q=numpy.random.randint(-100,100,size=(N,N))

C=mm(P,Q)
except MemoryError:
     print("Memory error")


try:
     A=numpy.random.randint(-1000,1000,size=(N,N))
     B=numpy.random.randint(-5000,5000,size=(N,N))
except MemoryError:
      print("Memory error")


try:

    D=mm(A,B)
    D=mm (D,C)
    print D
except NameError:
     print("name error")


elapsedTime = time.time() - startTime
     print elapsedTime
```

and I got RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars ERROR is any way to skip this error? are the answers that it shows, wrong?

Comment: Can someone who speaks better NumPy than me determine whether this is using int32's or int64's?  If the former, OP can probably just widen them and be done with it.  While we're at it, OP should probably just use `ndarray.dot()` to do matrix multiplication...

Comment: @Kevin there is no problem with dot but i have to it without using this functions,i think if i make the matrix values int64 it will be ok but i dont know how to do it!!

Comment: You could probably cast the arrays to int64 using [`astype()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy.ndarray.astype) before you do the matrix multiplication.

Comment: didnt work :( or maybe i couldnt use this way

Comment: What if you used [astype(float)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy.ndarray.astype) to produce floating point matrix items?

Answer (score 0):

to multiply arrays you can just use `numpy.dot(A,B)`

```py
 A=numpy.random.randint(-1000,1000,size=(1000,1000))
 B=numpy.random.randint(-5000,5000,size=(1000,1000))
 C=numpy.dot(A,B)
```

```py
>> array([[ -19276757, -143164893,  -46042782, ...,   54192473,  -11723491,
         -24682938],
       [ -13712042,  -81161007,  -10673794, ...,  -60976103,   12684946,
         -38034048],
       [ -33019063,  -31452735,    6885214, ...,  -11402430,  -67335345,
          28926860],
       ...,
       [ -75416394,  -86704514,   55883100, ...,   -9195721,   14717256,
           1028573],
       [ -73945244,   72442826,  -38529094, ...,   -1450784,   34663409,
         -88472364],
       [ -21366137,   91174501,   32863977, ...,   11465498,   57130349,
          47305071]])
```

Comment: i know but i dont want to use these functions , i just want to compare the performance of way u said and my way. but i my way got some problem